# expanding operation with if condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have following dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1234,0,1],[1234,1,2],[1234,0,3],[2256,1,4],[1234,0,5],[1234,1,6],[1234,0,7],[2256,0,8],[2256,1,9],[2256,0,10]],columns=['ID','result','time'])
```

***Example***

```
     ID  result  time
0  1234       0     1
1  1234       1     2
2  1234       0     3
3  2256       1     4
4  1234       0     5
5  1234       1     6
6  1234       0     7
7  2256       0     8
8  2256       1     9
9  2256       0     10
10 1234       1     11
```

I want to group by ID. Then, I would like to add column 'time_since_1' for each ID. 'time_since_1' is the duration of time since result became 1 for each ID. The time will reset ***after*** each ID's result becomes 1. So I need shift also.

***Desired output***

```
     ID  result  time time_since_1
0  1234       0     1            0  → Nothing hasn't happened yet
1  1234       1     2            0  → first time = 0 (ID = 1234)
2  1234       0     3            1  → 3-2 = 1        (ID = 1234)
3  2256       1     4            0  → first time = 0 (ID = 2256)
4  1234       0     5            3  → 5-2 = 3        (ID = 1234)
5  1234       1     6            4  → 6-2 = 4        (ID = 1234)  
6  1234       0     7            1  → 7-6 = 1        (ID = 1234)
7  2256       0     8            4  → 8-4 = 4        (ID = 2256) 
8  2256       1     9            5  → 9-4 = 5        (ID = 2256) 
9  2256       0     10           1  → 10-9 = 1       (ID = 2256)
10 1234       1     11           5  → 11-6 = 5       (ID = 1234)
```

I tried to make the code, and eventually I found that .expanding() may help in this case. So, I tried the code below.

```py
df['time_since_1'] = df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x.expanding().apply(lambda y: y['time'] - y[y['result']==1].tail(1)['time']))
```

This kind of thing didn't work because .expanding().apply() returns ndarray, and not sure how to handle these. I need to use expanding() and get last row of result=1's time, so that I can subtract recent row's time from it. I'm not sure how to do it.

Since expanding().apply() returns ndarray I tried to make dataframe out of it, but there also seems to be error, and not sure the correct approach.

```py
def func(y):
    df = pd.DataFrame(y,columns=['ID','result','time_since_1'])
    # filter here
    # return one value (time_since_1)

df['time_since_1'] = df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x.expanding().apply(lambda y: func(y))
```

Any different ideas or code help me. Thank you.

Comment: your output is inconsistent. At index 2,  `ID 1234` got calculate to `3-2=1`. However, jumping to index 6,  `ID 1234` doesn't get any calculation. It got reset to `0`. Why are they getting different calculation?

Comment: You are right. I was making mistake. I fixed index 6. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My attempt no is the expected solution, but maybe could help you...

```
r=df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x.where(x['result'].eq(1))['time'].shift().ffill().fillna(df['time']))
df['time_since_1']=df['time']-r.reset_index().sort_values('level_1').set_index('level_1')['time']
print(df)
      ID  result  time  time_since_1
0   1234       0     1           0.0
1   1234       1     2           0.0
2   1234       0     3           1.0
3   2256       1     4           0.0
4   1234       0     5           3.0
5   1234       1     6           4.0
6   1234       0     7           1.0
7   2256       0     8           4.0
8   2256       1     9           5.0
9   2256       0    10           1.0
10  1234       1    11           5.0
```

Comment: Thank you for positing. Actually, your answer seems to be right. I was making mistake on index 6. I fixed it from 0 to 7-6=1. I'll look into your solution from now!